# Custom Layouts are not saving after applying a layout to a page

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I have created custom layouts in my custom theme.The  layouts are appearing in Layouts tab in Edit mode. but when i apply a layout to a page and click on save, the layouts are not applying to page.Please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any underlying errors in SystemOut.log file on your system. Also pls post the method (in detailed steps) using which you created the custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a page layout to a page via the layout file itself through WebDav. Open your page in edit mode, open the edit page properties dialog, and click the Advanced tab.

Once on the Advanced tab, you can set the page layout template location using:

```
dav:fs-type1/path/to/layout/in/theme
```